Update data in SQL Server with scan function VFP
I want to update data in SQL Server using VFP 8. Below is my code
create cursor skedul1 (norekening N(13), ke N(2), pokok_kr N(12), bunga_kr N(12), pokok_sd N(12))
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 1, 0, 26400, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 2, 0, 26400, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 3, 0, 26800, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 4, 0, 26400, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 5, 0, 25500, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 6, 850000, 26400, 0)
select skedul1
m.value1 = skedule1.norekening
m.value2 = skedule1.ke
m.value3 = skedule1.pokok_kr
m.value5 = skedule1.bunga_kr

TEXT TO m.lcSQL TEXTMERGE noshow
UPDATE dbo.skedul
SET pokok_kr = ?m.value3,
pokok_sd = ?m.value4,
bunga_kr = ?m.value5
WHERE norekening = ?m.value1 and ke = ?m.value2
ENDTEXT

lnResult = SQLExec(Thisform.nHandle, m.lcSQL)
If m.lnResult < 0
Aerror(aWhy)
Messagebox(aWhy[2])
SQLDisconnect(0)
Return .F.
Else
Messagebox("Data Telah Update..!!")
thisform.PopulateGrid()
thisform.grid2.RecordSource = ""
Endif

Only one row has been changed. Can someone corrected my script?
note.. at variable m.value1 until m.value5 suppose be write with skedul1 not skedule1 also m.value4 = skedul1.pokok_sd

wait.. i got internet lagging..

BTW your question has nothing to do with SQL or SQL server.

What made you think you only insert one row? It inserts all of them and these lines were totally unnecessary:
SET SAFETY OFF
SELECT     skedul1
Zap
Set Safety off
select skedul1


whoops... i got mistake in here.. i will leave those statement..

Your code is missing SCAN / ENDSCAN.
create cursor skedul1 (norekening N(13), ke N(2), pokok_kr N(12), bunga_kr N(12), pokok_sd N(12))

insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 1, 0, 26400, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 2, 0, 26400, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 3, 0, 26800, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 4, 0, 26400, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 5, 0, 25500, 850000)
insert into skedul1 (norekening, ke, pokok_kr, pokok_sd, bunga_kr) values (1312124120052, 6, 850000, 26400, 0)

select skedul1
scan
    m.value1 = skedul1.norekening
    m.value2 = skedul1.ke
    m.value3 = skedul1.pokok_kr
    m.value4 = skedul1.pokok_sd
    m.value5 = skedul1.bunga_kr

    TEXT TO m.lcSQL TEXTMERGE noshow
    UPDATE dbo.skedul
    SET pokok_kr = ?m.value3,
    pokok_sd = ?m.value4,
    bunga_kr = ?m.value5
    WHERE norekening = ?m.value1 and ke = ?m.value2
    ENDTEXT

    lnResult = SQLExec(Thisform.nHandle, m.lcSQL)
    If m.lnResult < 0
        EXIT
    Endif
endscan

If m.lnResult < 0
    Aerror(aWhy)
    Messagebox(aWhy[2])
    SQLDisconnect(0)
    Return .F.
Endif

Messagebox("Data Telah Update..!!")
thisform.PopulateGrid()
thisform.grid2.RecordSource = ""


